# Client not receive message Signal R

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm implemented in my application sending data in real time, when sending from my C # .net client to a web client it reacts, it works, but on the contrary it doesn't work, it actually does the sending but my event doesn't start.

```
public class ClientServiceCommunication : Hub
{
    public void SendService(string obj)
    {
        Clients.Group("Server").SendAsync("ReceiveService", obj);
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        ConnectedUser.Ids.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
        if (ConnectedUser.Ids.Count == 1)
        {
            await JoinGroup("Server");
        }
        else
        {
            await JoinGroup("Web");
        }
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
```

//this is my method in other class that creates the listening to activate an event

```
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        ClientServiceConnection.hubConnection.On<string>("ReceiveWeb", (obj) =>
        {
            CommunicationEvent<DeviceMessage>.ReceivedFromWeb(obj);
        });
    }
```

//my event

```
    public LoaderDevice(LoaderConfig config)
    {
        _tcpConection = new TCPConnection(config.tcpConfig);
        _configuration = config;

        CommunicationEvent<EventArgs>.ReceiveWeb += CommEvent_ReceiveWeb;
    }

    private void CommEvent_ReceiveWeb(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DeviceMessage deserializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeviceMessage>(sender.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Message:" + deserializedObj);
    }

    public static void ReceivedFromWeb(string message)
    {
        if (ReceiveWeb != null)

            ReceiveWeb(message, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

Comment: try to send your message to each client ( loop on `Clients`) just to  see if the group mechanism has causing any issues.

Comment: hi @MoxGeek it works because the first connected client is always C # .net, so there is 1 C # client and the others are web, I believe the problem is happening in the hubConnection.on typing